# Nesting Ruby gems inside a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

How do I create a gem project nested inside my current Rails project?

I've got a Rails project with several parts that could easily be gems. I would like to extract these parts into gems but not leave the current Rails project. Creating new source control repos for the gems add additional complexity that project or organization is not ready or able to handle. These complexities will be overcome at some point and I would like to be ready.

So far I can only think of these items.

1. Relocate code to a single directory root. I'm guessing this would be in the `vendor` path
2. Create a `<something>.gemspec`
3. Link to the gem in the `Gemfile` of the Rails app

   ```
   gem 'my_lib_code', path: 'vendor/my_lib_code'
   ```

What else do I need to do? I'm sure I'm missing something important.

---

If this were a c project I would create another shared library that the make process spits out. Or if this where a c# project I would make a `.dll`. For Java I would...

I'm sure Ruby can do the same as all the other languages. Something that is a half way step between a normally fully extracted gem and just some code siting in my `lib` path.

Comment: It's called `vendor` not `vender`

Comment: I don't really understand your reasoning, gems are self-contained, external, reusable pieces of code with external API. What is a point of creating not-really-gems?

Comment: Added reasons to the question.  @MichaelSzyndel in this case the project does not want to vendor the .gem files and doesn't want a 2nd repo to manage yet. In the mean time I would like to isolate the code for testing and stability of the code.

Comment: Extract them into POROs in your lib or models directory. You can test them in isolation, and when you want to extract them to a gem you just delete them out of the repo and require the gem in the Gemfile.

Comment: The code is already in POROs and the lib directory. The code is still part of the Rails app. When I run tests they will run too. When it comes time to extract I still have to create files. I'm looking for the half way step. Right before you extract out into its own project.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfectly fine approach for a component-based architecture.

You have a single repository, a single test suite, and a single deployment process, while at the same time you are "forced" to think of clean interfaces and separation of concerns.

Of course if you are planning on sharing this functionality with other projects, an externally hosted (but not necessarily public) Gem would serve better.

Implementation wise, you can get some nifty ideas from Stephan Hagemann's talk at this year's RailsConf: "[Get started with Component-based Rails applications!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsRPxS7Cu_Q)"